# How to change default value of date filter in metabase?

Tags: date, filter, default-value, metabase

I am trying to write dynamic sql query in metabase-
I added date filter like that (using snowflake for query):

```
select * from my_table where date > {{date_filter}}
```

after that I needed to set default value of yesterday to date_filter, so I write this:

```
select * from my_table where date > [[{{date_filter}} #]]dateadd(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```

and it worked, when I ran this query- I got the right output.

BUT- when I changed the date in the calendar that metabase provided for date types- I got this error:

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 142 unexpected '#D'. syntax error line 1 at position 156 unexpected '-'. syntax error line 1 at position 172 unexpected '('.
```

How can I change date_filter default value without getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

finally found a workaround that solve the problem.

in UI settings, define date_filter as REQUIRED and assign static default value- for example 01.01.2015 if my table contains data starting of 2016.

in sql query- I wrote that:

```
select * from my_table where date > case when year({{date_filter}}) = 2015 then dateadd(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) else {{date_filter}} end
```

which means:

if I won't select any date in date_filter calender- date_filter year value will be 2015 (as I defined date_filter = 01.01.2015) so I will compare DATE against dateadd(DAY, -1, GETDATE()).

but if I WILL select value in date_filter calender, then year(date_filter) will be different than 2015 (as I said, I won't choose date before 2016 because I have no data before 2016 in my table) so I will compare DATE against {{date_filter}} value which I just selected.